# JavaScript not working after redirecting to the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new on web-developing and I'm not being able to find the answer to my problem anywhere. I have a list of elements an when you click on one of them a popup shows up with a  on it. When you hit the submit button, it makes a $_POST to "modificarPlato.php", and since I want to stay in the first page, I've added header("Location: pedido.php"); at the end of the php so it returns back to the mainpage. But when it redirects to pedido.php, any  on it doesn't work. That means that the popup with the  is not showing up when I click on the element.

To simplify it, I've made a simple function that fills an h2 on the body onLoad() but that's not working either.

I have the following pedido.php page (I'm omitting some code because is not relevant):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/web.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
</head>
<h2 id="prueba" ></h2>
<body onLoad="fill()">
    <ul>
    <?php
        $_SESSION["arrayFilas"] = array();
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $_SESSION['results'], SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
            $str=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $row['nombre']);
            if (strcmp($row['imageUrl'],"") != 0) $aux = $row['imageUrl'];
            else $aux = "http://www.51allout.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Image-not-found.gif";
            echo "<li style='background-image: url(".$aux.")'> 
                <a id='".$str."' class='edit' href='#test' data-rel='popup' onClick='rellenarFormulario(this)'> </a>
                 <div id='textobanner'>
                    <h2 id='textobannerreal' style='color:white'>".$row['nombre']."</h2>
                </div></li>"; 
            array_push($_SESSION["arrayFilas"], $row);
            $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
        }

    ?>
        <li  style="background-image: url(https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/o_collection_png/green_dark_grey/512x512/plain/add.png)">
        <a id="addButton" href='#test' data-rel="popup" onClick="formularioAdd()"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div data-role="popup" data-history=false id="test"  class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
      <form  id="formulario" action="insertarNuevo.php" method="POST">
                <h2 id="pruebados"></h2>
              <input type="text" id="nombrePlato" name="nombrePlato" value="" placeholder="Introduce aquí el nombre del plato" size="50">
              <br>
              <br>
              <!--Preguntas de radio --> 
              <input type="hidden" id="hiddenId" name="hiddenId">
              <b>Elige el tipo de plato</b><br>
              <input type="radio" name="pregunta" id="radioPri" value="Respuesta1">
              Primero<br>
              <input type="radio" name="pregunta" id="radioSeg"value="Respuesta2">
              Segundo<br>
              <input type="radio" name="pregunta" id="radioTer"value="Respuesta3">
              Postre<br>
              <br>
              <b>Descripción del plato:</b><br>
              <!--TEXTAREA-->
              <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <b>Ingredientes:</b><br>
              <!--TEXTAREA-->
              <textarea id="ingredientes" name="ingredientes" value="" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
              <br>
              <!--SELECT--> 
              <b>Precio</b><br>
              <input type="text" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="Introduce aquí el precio del plato" size="50">
              <br>
              <br>
              <b>Imagen</b><br>
              <input type="text" id="imagen" name="imagen" placeholder="Introduce aquí la url de la imagen" size="50">
              <br>
              <br>
              <button type="submit" id="botonEnvio" name="botonEnvio" value="submit"></button>
            </form>
    </div>

   </body>
   </html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fill(){
        document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML="se ha abierto el popup";
    }
</script>
```

And the form calls modificarPlato.php, which updates data on an db:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>

     <?php
                /* CODE TO CONNECT TO THE DB*/

                header("Location: pedido.php");
                exit;

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if there's any additional information that you may need, and sorry for my english skills . Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the javascript function `rellenar`?

Comment: You should look into AJAX

Comment: What you want to do

Comment: Do you have any script errors in the browser console?

Comment: Shouldn't `exit;` be `exit();`?

Comment: @Jerodev sorry, rellenar is fill, I've changed the name from spanish to english but forgot to change it everywhere

Comment: @mjw no, there aren't any errors in the browser console

Comment: I see several problems, at least with your sample code. First, you have different names for the function where it's defined and where it's called in the body onLoad handler. Also, you shouldn't declare your <script> section after the closing </html> tag. Place it before the closing </body> tag. The <h2> tag should be after the opening <body> tag, not before. I also see you're including two different versions of jQuery, which can only cause problems.

Comment: @Musa I have a list of elements. When you click on any of them it opens a popup with a form on it. Once you fill the form and press the submit button, it calls another php files that sends the info inside the form to the sql db, and then goes back to the main page. But when you go back, you can't open the popup again. That's what I want to fix.

Comment: @FernandoEcheverria so I made a lot of research today and found out that the problem is, as you suggested, to include two different versions of jQuery. However the popup is not working if I delete any of them, so I wil have to find another way. Since you were the one who suggested it, if you want to, put this as an answer and i will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems, at least with your sample code:

- First, you have different names for the function where it's defined and where it's called in the body `onLoad` handler (`rellenar` and `fill`).
- Also, you shouldn't declare your `<script>` section after the closing `</html>` tag. Place it before the closing `</body>` tag.
- The `<h2>` tag should be after the opening `<body>` tag, not before.
- I also see you're including two different versions of *jQuery*, which can only cause problems.